# Induction heater - please identify device

Tags: sensor

[image: Unknown device]

I am trying to identify this device. It is located on the cooling water input line of an induction heater. The grey insulated wire is too thin to carry much current, but it couples with another toroid with a single turn thick conductor as shown in the second picture. I have also added the only circuit diagram available ... for what it is worth.
[image: Transformer coupling with sensor]

[image: Somewhat useless circuit description]

Comment: Wild guess: Current transformer for some kind of safety ground fault interrupter? Where do the red wires in the bottom of the picture go?

Comment: Agreed. Current transformer. It looks like a low-frequency CT though and most induction heaters are low radio-frequency.

Comment: If it is a CT, shouldn't that copper pipe be running *through* the torroid core.?

Comment: Is it trying to be one of those "water softener" devices?

Comment: I'm going to guess it generates a magnetic field that funnels any metallic particles down the other pipe.

Comment: @brhans You would imagine the pipe would go through the core, though the "secondary" windings if that's what they are do go around the pipe meaning you would get some mutual inductance.  The core wouldn't do you much good though.  But not a great way to build a current transformer, so it's probably something else.

Comment: It may just be a water cooled inductor... if we knew what the rest of the circuitry looked like we could have a clue.

Comment: Ground fault detection was my take as well, but I can't figure out the physics. I'll post the only "circuit diagram" I have, but it seems pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the induction heater circuits I am looking at on line have a working coil in addition to a matching coil or choke coil.

[image]

[image]

As such I am going to guess what you are looking at is that secondary coil which is continuously water cooled.

Comment: Agreed, this makes more sense than anything else.  Looks like there's a cooling plate that the core is mounted to which makes contact with the copper pipe. +1

Comment: Sounds plausible, I'll check it out sometime this week and get back to you.

Comment: The secondary coil (the choke in your diagram) is the coil that projects from the machine to induce current in the workpiece. That coil is tubular and water-cooled.

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of a snubber circuit.
As capacitor is connection across positive and negative and negative leg of a capacitor is going from inside of a toroidal core .
As the spikes generated across IGBT, capacitor charges and it delivers the energy to toroidal core which is then wasted at the second core which is cooled by water copper pipe.
One can use a 100watt resistor also but this design is cost saving but not reliable.

Comment: Yours seems like the most plausible and authoritative explanation.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just pre-heating the water before it enters to avoid thermal shock by creating a saturated magnetic core that gets warm.

Comment: I was thinking that too.. but then why not just heat the pipe directly with heater wire.

Comment: With the plastic zip-ties ... ? Unlikely.